# how to prevent css inherit?

Tags: html, css

What is so annoying about CSS when you add style in the css class, it may apply other element/class by itself.

What the best way to prevent that?

For example:

HTML:

```
<div class='main-content'>
    <p> Hello World </p> 
    <span> Test One </span>
    <div class='column'>
        <span> Test Two</span>
    </div> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main-content span {
    background: #921192;
    color: white;
    padding: 3px 4px;
    margin: 0 5px;
}


.column  span {
    font-size:20px;
    text-transform:none;
    display:inline-block;
}​
```

I do not want "Test Two" `<span>` to have a background color.

Test: http://jsfiddle.net/szm9c/1/

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible to not inherit in CSS. If you don't want a specific span to not not have certain styles, you'll have to target it specifically and override the styles, or you'll have to target other spans (with a class, for example) and apply the styles to them.

Comment: @NADH the problem the OP describes is not _actually_ a style inheritance problem, just a selector one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a selector that actually selects the elements you want. In this case `>`, the [child selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors), will suffice.

```
.main-content > span {
    background: #921192;
    color: white;
    padding: 3px 4px;
    margin: 0 5px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/mQFz2/

Comment: but I think this question can have more general answer. Its better to use classes...

Answer (score 2):

Use `.main-content > span`, that selects only directly descendent elements.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with inheritance.

To use CSS properly, assign properties to elements using selectors that match only the elements that you wish to affect. (The example given is far too artificial for a useful analysis and for constructive suggestions on a better approach.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
.main-content > span {
background: #921192;
color: white;
padding: 3px 4px;
margin: 0 5px;
}
```

If you use like `.main-content > span` that style will only affect to the `immediate child` spans of `.main-content` class

Answer (score 0):

Just use all: initial at your root element.

```
.selector 
{
    all: initial;
}
```